# Why isn't close_on_exec the default configuration?

Tags: linux, exec

Since there seems no way to use already opened fd after `exec`,

why isn't this flag the default?

Answer (score 5):

File descriptors *can* be used past an `exec` call; that's how the Unix utilities get their standard input/output/error fds from the shell, for example.

Close-on-exec is not the default because the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) (and Unix tradition) mandates the opposite behavior:

> File descriptors open in the calling process image shall remain open in the new process image, except for those whose close-on- exec flag `FD_CLOEXEC` is set.

Comment: Is there any other use case besides the input/output/error fds?

Comment: Oops, brain fart. Well, there is support for arbitrary fd redirection in modern shells, which must have been introduced with a reason; though I've never found that useful myself.

Answer (score 2):

Because on UNIX one of the most used features is/was piping streams between processes - and you cannot do that if the CLOEXEC flag is set (child process cannot inherit file descriptor(s), e.g.: STDOUT_FILENO).

And no, it is not true that you cannot use inherited file descriptors after exec (example: standard streams). You also can use any inherited file descriptor as long as you know its value (it is an integer). This value is often passed to a child process by argument (quite a few UNIX programs do that), or you can do this any other way using any IPC (Inter-Process Communication) mechanism of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mind getting an more complete answer to this, but it's quite easy to guess it's for backward compatibility. the close-on-exec flag had to be introduced sometime. Code existing from before that time didn't know about it, and wouldn't work correctly unless changed. Therefore it's off by default.

Unfortunately bugs happen because of this, a daemon process forking a cgi might leave the listen socket open, and if the cgi doesn't quit or close it, the daemon can not be restarted. So I agree with you that it's not really a good default.